# Problem with System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am having a few troubles with a set of hosted code on an WS2K8 R2 box with IIS 7. I have another server running WS2008 that does not encounter the same issue. I have copied the application code from the old server so that it is identical.

The exception thrown in my server side logs is:

```
"ModuleLoadException: The C++ module failed to load while attempting to initialize the default appdomain."
```

I also have an error being returned in VS2010 at the same time:

```
Unable to find assembly 'msvcm80, Version=8.0.50727.4927, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

I have checked and the correct version of msvcm80 is on the server in the "C:\Windows\winsxs" folder. I have also installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64) and (x86).

I cannot see why the error might be thrown??

My debugging expierence is low so please bear with me.

Comment: This is C++/CLI? IIRC the `vcredist` is for the unmanaged part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-checked the version details. It appears that it was a requirement of the Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributible. I re-installed all versions of it on the server and applied the security hotfixes.

After a re-boot and testing in IIS the issue has now gone from my log files.

I did check the comparison between the two servers and wasnt that happy copying the files over. I felt it was best to try this method first.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

msvcm80 is a .NET Framework mixed assembly (microsoft visual c++ managed + unmanaged). You might try to find this file on the second server and place near your application on the first server machine.

*Note: .Net Framework Runtime requires exact version of an assembly (8.0.50727.4927 in your case).*

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response. I have check the folders and both servers are running the same versions. Only issue is that one (working) is running Windows Server 2008 and the other (not working) is running Windows Server 2008 R2. Is it ok to copy the files servers? They are the same version number.

Comment: Please check if those files both compiled for x64 architecture.